# GOG game install "Exit with return code 31488"

Tags: 22.04, games, lutris

I've just updated from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20 then 22.04, and I'm trying to reinstall a game I had on 18.04 (specifically Heroes3) via Lutris, but it keeps crashing with the following error "Exit with return code 31488"

any ideas? I can only find discussions on return code 256. also I'm a bit of a noob haha

thank you!